# How does a wormhole form?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, singularities, wormholes

I heard about [wormholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole). I know that they are paths that can be got by contracting spacetime.
But, how does a wormhole form?

Comment: Since nobody has yet seen a wormhole, you will only get guesses as to how they are formed, if they are even real.